# How to address the issue of global pooling?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification

Although global pooling helps reduce model parameters and effectively prevents overfitting, it also sacrifices a significant amount of local or fine-grained information. Why is global pooling still prevalent in image classification models? How to address the limitations of global pooling?